# Changing the value of the elements of a set data structure?

Tags: c++, set

I have a `set < long long > A`. After inserting 500 elements:

```
ll k;
for ( int i=0 ; i<500 ; i++ ) {
    cin >> k ;
    A.insert (k) ;
}
```

now when I want to change the value of elements like :

```
A[0]--;
```

The compiler gives me this error:

> no match for 'operator[]' in 'A[0]'

I would appreciate if you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

A set is a collection of elements, where you either "have" or "don't" have an element (so if you `insert` the number `6` five times, it still only counts the same as once). So to remove elements you `erase` it. It doesn't make much sense to use `[]` on a set (or to do `--` on what it returns).

Perhaps you are looking to use another container type - perhaps a `map<long long, int> B`, where you use `B[k]++;`. Then you can do `B[0]--;` later on - although if `0` wasn't used, you will end up with `-1` in that element, so you may want to use `(*B.begin())--;` instead - really depends on what you are trying to achieve.